# cannot import name 'flash_attn_func' from 'flash_attn'

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, llama

try to load llama2 model:

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=device_map
)
```

with these bnb_config:

```
BitsAndBytesConfig {
  "bnb_4bit_compute_dtype": "bfloat16",
  "bnb_4bit_quant_type": "nf4",
  "bnb_4bit_use_double_quant": true,
  "llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload": false,
  "llm_int8_has_fp16_weight": false,
  "llm_int8_skip_modules": null,
  "llm_int8_threshold": 6.0,
  "load_in_4bit": true,
  "load_in_8bit": false,
  "quant_method": "bitsandbytes"
}
```

and I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.llama.modeling_llama because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'flash_attn_func' from 'flash_attn' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flash_attn/__init__.py)
```

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same error when finetuning llama2 model, the solution will be to revert to the previous version of transformers.

```
pip install transformers==4.33.1 --upgrade
```

This should work.

Comment: can you please mention working version of these libraries if you are using them accelerate, peft, bitsandbytes